# Equivalent of fork do for windows machines in ruby

Tags: ruby, fork

I have a ruby script that forks some of the code to run it in the background and exit the command line.

The code:

```
fork do
  #Example background code
  x = 0

  while x < 100 do
     File.write("./example_file.txt", x.to_s, Mode: "a")
  end
end
```

I would like to have that same script run on windows systems without the need for extra gems/libraries. I have looked at spawn() but couldn't get it to work for my needs.

Comment: Would you mind adding the error that is happening on windows?

Comment: Why does the precise error message matter? `fork` doesn't exist on Windows, the exact words in the error message telling you that it doesn't exist, don't change the fact that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @PedroPaiva ```fork() function is unimplemented on this machine```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fork` and Windows don't really go well together. The philosophy towards processes in Unix and Windows is very different.

In Unix, processes are the primary mechanism for functional decomposition. I.e. in Unix, an application or a service would be composed as a pipeline of multiple cooperating processes. Processes are used in Unix in a similar way as objects are in Ruby. In order for that to work, processes are *cheap* and *lightweight*.

In Windows, *components* are the primary mechanism for functional decomposition. I.e. in Windows, an application or a service would consist of a *single* process, implemented using multiple components. *Components* are used like objects in Ruby or processes in Unix. That means processes in Windows do not need to be cheap or lightweight, and in fact, they are pretty expensive, heavy, and slow to create and destroy.

In addition to processes being used very differently and being more expensive, they are also *interacted with* very differently. The APIs for creating, managing, and destroying processes are very different. There is no exact equivalent to `fork` in Windows, and no easy, performant way to implement it.

Unfortunately, going to TruffleRuby or JRuby also won't help: while TruffleRuby's and JRuby's Windows support traditionally tends to be even better than YARV's, this does *not* apply to `fork` because the JVM does not allow it: `forking` on the JVM creates a fork which has only the main thread in it, but none of the GC, compiler, I/O, or other helper and auxiliary threads, which leaves you with a broken JVM. It only really works if you *immediately* `exec` a different process, thus exiting the JVM.

That being said, this *particular* usage of `Kernel#fork` could *probably* be implemented on JRuby, because (if I remember correctly), you can instantiate multiple JRuby instances in the same JVM. So, for this particular usage, where you only execute some Ruby code in the background, you don't actually *need* to `fork`, you could spin up a new JRuby instance in a different thread.

But as far as I know, that is not implemented. (Might make an interesting project for a first contribution, though!)

The closest equivalent to your code using [`Kernel#spawn`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) in Windows would probably be something like:

```ruby
spawn(RbConfig.ruby, '-e' << <<~BLOCK_END)
  #Example background code
  x = 0

  while x < 100 do
     File.write("./example_file.txt", x.to_s, Mode: "a")
  end
BLOCK_END
```

But that is not the correct way to approach your problem. You are approaching this as an X/Y problem: you have problem **X**. You know that the solution *in Unix* is **Y**. Now, instead of asking the question "how do I solve *problem* **X** on Windows", you are asking the question "how do I *implement* solution **Y** on Windows", without even questioning whether **Y** is the *right* solution.

So, your question should not be what is the equivalent of `fork` in Windows, but rather how to design an application in Windows.